# Ubuntu 18.04 dual screen don't work after reboot

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, display-resolution

I have Dell Optiplex 3020 desktop. I have dual screen setting.
Main screen is connected to HDMI and second smaller monitor is connected to VGA.
System don't see all resolutions available for VGA (only up to 1024x768).
I know how to fix that- i put in console:
xrandr --newmode "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
and then:
xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1440x900_60.00

Then I configure everything in settings. Everything seems to work ok. I restart PC- GRUB by default is displayed on my HDMI screen, splash screen too. After I give my password screen (HDMI) goes off and I see only things on screen VGA in resolution 1024x768, all changes done by me seems to be forgotten by system.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution.
First I run command to get the mode for my screen resolution- in that case it's 1440x900:

```
cvt 1440 900
```

output is in my case:

```
# 1440x900 59.89 Hz (CVT 1.30MA) hsync: 55.93 kHz; pclk: 106.50 MHz
Modeline "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 
934 -hsync +vsync
```

I copy starting from "1440x900_600" and to the end.
Then I add mode by commands:

```
xrandr --newmode "1440x900_60.00" 106.50 1440 1528 1672 1904 900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
```

and

```
xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1440x900_60.00
```

Since now I can set that resolution for my screen.
But that do not work after restart, so I made simple script. I put that script in ~/.config/autostart/ folder (you can name it dualscreen.sh) and it looks like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

xrandr --newmode "1440x900_60.00" 106.50 1440 1528 1672 1904 900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1440x900_60.00

#after that line it is not neccessary
sleep 1s
xdotool mousemove 2400 550
```

Last two lines are here to move mouse pointer to my main screen (try values which will be ok for you). You need to install xdotool by:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

There is sleep 1s which makes 1 second delay before executing last command, otherwise mouse was moved only to the edge of second screen (by default mouse pointer started on second screen).